# How to move an object to a specific position in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm currently in development of a card game of sorts, and when a user plays a card, I want that card to move from its current location in the players hand to the "face up" pile on the screen.

Edit: To answer some questions, and make the question/answers clean, here is some of my code.

```
+(id)card:(NSString*)suit :(int) value {
HHCard *card = [HHCard new];
card.value = value;
card.suit = suit;
//used for selection of cards during human turn
card.isSelected = false;
return card;
}
```

Comment: Is your card object a `UIView`?

Comment: Core Animation would work fine for this. In order to get a useful answer you'll need to provide some detail about your setup. What platform is this for? What is your view hierarchy? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @jtbandes I answered  your questions in my question, let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for not answering the question sooner, however the answer is quite simple. In order to move an object, in this example a 'card' to the desired location on the screen, create a CGPoint that contains the point where you wish your object to move, and then have your object run the SKAction moveTo:(CGPoint)duration:(NSTimeInterval).

```
CGPoint newPosition = {newX,newY};
[yourObject runAction:[SKAction moveTo:newPosition duration:lengthOfAnimation]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your card has to be associated with an UIView of some kind. Why not use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:

Then in your animations block you just change the x and y coordinates to where you want the card to go. It will animate it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Their are 4 methods that has been provided to us, through which we can track the touch made to a view. the methods are below :

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

You just need to apply these methods in your controller class and then can track the location of your view in these method accordingly.

Hope this may help.